# How to include specific file if display specific page

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add in layouts/frontend.blade.php

include diferrent seo.blade.php file according to page.

```
@if (page == 'home')
   @include('partials.seo')
@endif

@if (page == 'about')
  @include('partials.seo2')
@endif
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Segments :

```
@if (request()->segment(0) == 'home')
   @include('partials.seo')
@endif

@if (request()->segment(0) == 'about')
  @include('partials.seo2')
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you it work with one time == not twice . but dont show the partials.seo2 page.

Comment: `segments` are an array that starts at index `0`. if the url is `domain.com/home/about` then the url, `segment(0)` will be `home` and `segment(1)` will be `about`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. Not load the partials.seo

Comment: How is your url look like, can you paste it here

Comment: In partials.seo there is this code:  <title> {{ $general->sitename(__($page_title)) }}</title>
    <meta name="title" Content="{{ $general->sitename(__($page_title)) }}">
    <meta name="description" content="{{ $seo->description }}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ implode(',',$seo->keywords) }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ getImage(imagePath()['logoIcon']['path'] .'/favicon.png') }}" type="image/x-icon"> and diferrent in partials.seo2